# MySQL: create a different partition for each ID inside a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, partitioning

I read about partitioning in MySQL, and would like to know how to use this in my situation:

I have a project where I store huge csv-files inside a database.

For this I have one table `'csvfiles'` and another table `'csvdata'`.

Queries are only made on one csv-file at the time, so my idea is to create a new partition in `csvdata`  *for each different primary key-value* in `csvfiles` every time a csv-file is added. 
Ideally this should be done automatically, inside a trigger would be great.

Could anybody tell me if this is a valid setup, and how this could be realized?

Comment: Your idea boils down to creating a separate table for each key-value pair (because that's pretty much what partitions are). Really, it seems you're abusing the RDBMS

Comment: No, I only want to create a partition in 'csvdata' for each masterid in 'csvfiles', because the amount of data in 'cvsdata' for each masterid is so huge.

Comment: How often you add new files? Have you considered `MERGE` tables?